# How can I suppress a method from getting triggered?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a windows forms application that has a check box regarding the application being added to start up (via registry). If the user checks the box, the CheckedChanged event handler triggers a method that attempts to add the application to the registry. If, for any reason, this fails, I want to revert the check box to its unchecked state, however doing so triggers the method again recursively. How can I avoid this?

Similarly, when the application first loads, I look at the registry and accordingly set the initial state of the checkbox. When I programmatically set the state of the checkbox, the even handler fires, which I do not want.

Is there any way I can suppress the even handler from triggering the CheckedChanged method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple flag would suffice.

```
bool flag;

void ClickEventHandler(Object server, EventArgs e)
{
   if (flag) return;
   ....
}
```

And set the flag accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to disconnect the handler and reconnect it:

```
void CheckCbxProgrammatically(bool check)
{
    myCbx.CheckedChanged -= HandleCheckedChanged;
    myCbx.Checked = check;
    myCbx.CheckedChanged += HandleCheckedChanged;
}
```

You don't want to juggle state when you can avoid it.

Comment: while this works undoubtfully, it has the overhead of unsubscribing and subscribing to the event handler.

Comment: @Paulo that overhead is trivial

Comment: Thanks for the alternate route, but I think I'll go with the global variable.

Comment: But isn't this also just "juggling state" in its own way?

Comment: @Dan no, everything happens in the stack frame. In the other approach, the member variable can be modified independently and you have multiple (potential) control flows.

Comment: @Rex M: Everything happens in the stack frame if you make sure everything happens in the stack frame. This is no more or less true of an event than it is of a field; code elsewhere could just as easily resubscribe to your event as it could modify a member variable. I'm just not seeing how it's fundamentally any different.

Comment: @Dan the difference is that this can *only* happen *through* the prescribed call. The other approach *could* happen through the prescribed call, but it assumes a single program flow for the state to be managed in an expected way. That is how state introduces higher risk of bugs. Granted this is a small, low-risk example, but simple examples are best for learning.

Comment: @Rex: Sorry, just for clarity's sake—what do you mean by "prescribed call"? It sounds like you're saying that in the approach you're advocating, the state in question (the event's subscribers, in this case) can only be modified through `CheckCbxProgrammatically`; but clearly that's not the case. So I suspect I must be misunderstanding your argument slightly.

Comment: @Dan when calling the example method, *regardless of program flow*, it will guarantee 1) the value is modified; 2) the handler is not invoked when the value is modified; 3) the handler is reinstated so the call is (loosely) side-effect-free, other than the value change. With a member variable, the value and the method can be operated on independently of each other via other calls, even though the *intent* is probably that they should behaviorally be *very* tightly coupled together. So the behavior is not guaranteed regardless of program flow, it requires the developer *maintain* proper flow.

Comment: @Rex: I get what you're saying from the standpoint of what is "normal"; however, I disagree with you that this approach makes quite the guarantees you say it does. For example I recognize that if I use a member field, there is the risk that some code elsewhere might set the field under my nose. But that would just be a dumb mistake on my part. Similarly, it's possible I may accidentally subscribe to an event *twice* with the same handler, in which case the use of `-=` will *not* guarantee that it won't be invoked when the value is modified. But again, that would be my own dumb mistake.

Comment: @Rex: In other words I really just think this does the same thing as a flag—just using an event delegate's invocation list as that flag instead of a simple `bool` field. I *will* concede that an invocation list is a lot less "visible" than a field and thus this approach seems better protected against accidental manipulation.

Comment: @Dan dumb mistakes are what bugs are :)

Comment: @Rex: Right, so the same dumb mistake/bug is possible in either case. Ultimately I'm only questioning your portrayal of this approach as somehow *not* "juggling state"; in any case, I think I'll just let it go ;)

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of cases, I declare a global `bool isCalledManually` and set it to true when I don't want it to trigger the event. In the event:

```
If(isCalledManually)
    isCalledManually = false;
Else
    // do your operations.
```